# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column in 'where' clause

Tags: php, mysql

I've already checked other questions in here and tried everything i saw but couldn't solve my problem.

Details are above ;

**`main.js`** // **ajax query part**

```
$("#register").submit(function (event, request) {
    var password = $(this).find('input[name="objPassword"]').val();
    var namesurname = $(this).find('input[name="objNameSurname"]').val();
    var email = $(this).find('input[name="objEmail"]').val();
    var gsm = $(this).find('input[name="objGsm"]').val();
    var adres = $(this).find('input[name="objAddress"]').val();
    var termsOk = $(this).find('input[name="objAcceptTerms"]').val();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

    var postMessage;
    if (postMessage) {
        postMessage.abort();
    }

    var postData = {
        "objPass": password,
        "objNameSurname": namesurname,
        "objEmail": email,
        "objGsm": parseInt(gsm),
        "objAdres": adres,
        "objTerms": termsOk
    };

    // console.log(postData);
    // alert(password);

    postMessage = $.post(formURL, postData, function (data) {
        console.log("Data: " + data);
    });

...
```

**`register.php`**

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_trop@Dubai;charset=utf8','root','mysql');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if (isset($_POST)) {

// CHECK IF PASSWORD ALREADY IN USE
$objP = clear(strtoupper($_POST['objPass'])); // Get Ajax Data

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Id,PassNumber FROM tblRecords WHERE PassNumber = '.$objP.'');
$stmt->execute();
$PassResult = $stsmt->fetchAll;
// (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

if($PassResult) {
$data = array('FAIL' => 'GIRILEN SIFRE DAHA ONCE KULLANILMIS', 'postData : ' => $_POST);
echo json_encode($data);

} else {
$data = array('SUCCESS' => 'SIFRE BOSTA', 'postData' => $_POST);
echo json_encode($data);
```

[image: MySQL table details like :]

[image: Error i got]

**MySQL table details like :**
**ERROR I'VE GOT**
I've got **1** record in my **tblRecords** which up there.

I have a form on my landing page. First input called **objPassword** and it has to compare values in **PassNumber** column of **tblRecords** table.

The problem is it says that my value of input does not exist in my table. Its a value of input. The other one is a column of a table.

How to compare values between input and column with these codes?

Comment: QUotes problem in query it would be `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Id,PassNumber FROM tblRecords WHERE PassNumber = ".$objP);
`

Comment: your PassNumber column is varchar, that's why. MySQL is expecting a string not an integer

Comment: Your where value needs to be between quotes as it's a string. Do `$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Id,PassNumber FROM tblRecords WHERE PassNumber = "'.$objP.'"');`

Comment: Depending on what `clear` does you may be open to SQL injections as well. You should prepare your prepared statements. e.g. `$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Id,PassNumber FROM tblRecords WHERE PassNumber = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($objP));`

Comment: really not sure about your typos, holding back on posting an "answer".

Comment: @DFayet thats also worked. i've missed one of these quote now that worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bindParam` rather than substituting the value into the query. Then you don't have to worry about quoting and escaping the value.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Id,PassNumber FROM tblRecords WHERE PassNumber = :passnum');
$stmt->bindParam(':passnum', $objP);
$stmt->execute();
$PassResult = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: thanks thats worked and i think its more secure way to compare data between variable and database data. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`$objP` is `13123ASD` which means that `PassNumber = '.$objP.'` is `PassNumber = 13123ASD`, and as `13123ASD` is not being quoted it's being treated as a column name. You need to quote it:

```
'SELECT Id,PassNumber FROM tblRecords WHERE PassNumber = "'.$objP.'"'
```

Although ideally you should bind the parameter.

Comment: thats worked also. i've tried quote before but missed one of them :) thanks again